# Meteor collections: upsert w/ array

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query

Forms of this question have been asked a few times, but I've been unable to find a solution:

I have a schema like this (simplified):

```
StatusObject = new SimpleSchema({
   statusArray: [statusSchema]
});
```

where `statusSchema` is

```
{
    topicId:{
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    someInfo:{
        type: Number,
        optional: true,
        decimal: true
    },
    otherInfo:{
        type: Number,
        optional: true
    }
}
```

I am trying to `upsert` - with the following meteor method code:

```
var upsertResult = BasicInfo.update({
  userId: this.userId, 
  statusArray: {
    $elemMatch: { topicId : newStatus.topicId }
  }
}, { 
  $set: {
    "statusArray.$.topicId": newStatus.topicId,
    "statusArray.$.someInfo": newStatus.someInfo,
    "statusArray.$.otherInfo": newStatus.otherInfo
  }         
}, {
  multi: true,
  upsert: true
});
```

But I keep getting an error: `statusArray must be an array`
I thought by adding the `$`, I was making sure it is recognized as an array? What am I missing?

Comment: What is `topicCompletion` field in your query? Did you mean `statusArray` instead?

Comment: yes, sorry - was simplifying code & missed that. changing now.

Comment: Well, _now_ using `$` is justified. Although, your intention still isn't clear. Do you want to add another object into `statusArray` array or update existing object in it?

Comment: I would like to have exactly 1 object that has topicId=x in the array. (ie the topicId field should be unique across all array elements). Then i would like to update the someInfo and otherInfo of that array element

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Last question: if there are no documents with `statusArray.topicId` matching `newStatus.topicId`? Create new document or just push new object into `statusArray` array?

Comment: the latter - just push a new object (`newStatus` in the code above) into `statusArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems (after your clarification comments), that you want to find a document with particular `userId` and modify its `statusArray` array using one of these scenarios:

- Update existing object with particular `topicId` value;
- Add a new object if the array doens't have one with particular `topicId` value.

Unfortunately, you can't make it work using just one DB query, so it should be like this:

```js
// try to update record
const updateResult = BasicInfo.update({
  userId: this.userId, 
  'statusArray.topicId': newStatus.topicId
}, { 
  $set: {
    "statusArray.$": newStatus
  }         
});

if (!updateResult) {
  // insert new record to array or create new document
  BasicInfo.update({
    userId: this.userId
  }, {
    $push: {
      statusArray: newStatus
    },
    $setOnInsert: {
      // other needed fields
    }
  }, {
    upsert: true
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Extremely clear & helpful. Sorry for delay in trying out this solution - was backlogged.

Comment: @ASX Don't worry, I'm glad it helped you :)

Answer (score -1):

Your code is treating StatusArray as an object,

Before you do the upsert, build the status array first, assuming that your current value is `currentRecord`

```
newStatusArray = currentRecord.statusArray
newStatusArray.push({
  topicId: newStatus.topicId,
  someInfo : newStatus.someInfo,
  otherInfo: newStatus.otherInfo
})
```

and in the upsert, simply refer to it like this

```
$set: { statusArray: newStatusArray}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this requires me to pull out the entire array first, then re-save it to the database - which becomes very inefficient no?

Comment: Efficiency isn't a major problem, because it will have to retrieve the data anyway. unless you have thousands of elements in the array in which case your data design isn't right. It may be possible to update an individual element, in which case I think you would say `$set: {"statusArray[x]": newValues}` (where x is the index of the element you want to update)You could try that

Comment: I see where you got the `$` thing from the mongo doco. MiniMongo doesn't support the full Mongo interface, so Meteor basically only offers a subset (even on the server)

Comment: Right i see. Also not sure of upsert capabilities in Mongodb itself i guess. So for now I basically remove the array element containing topicId , then add it back  to the array as you mentioned...but still trying to figure out more of an upsert solution, if possible, that changes just 1 field of 1 object in the array - with many users this is taxing on the server.